# Why does package javax.servlet still does not exist even after setting the classpath?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using jdk1.5.0 and Tomcat 5.5. I recently edited the class path to

```
javac -cp.;/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/lib/servlet-api.jar
```

and i also created a default servlet folder i was required to create which should be located at

```
C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes.
```

but i still get the same errors

```
package javax.servlet does not exist
package javax.servlet.http does not exist
```

and i don't know if

```
Failed to load Main-class manifest attribute
```

from JVM Launcher has nothing to do with the errors i got.

Thank you for taking time to help.

Comment: Does the error occurs at compile time or at run time ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta  The error happens at compile time

Answer (score 2):

Try adding quotes and using backslashes. I think the space in "Program Files" etc. will break the line into another argument.

```
javac -cp ".;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\lib\servlet-api.jar"
```

Comment: Thanks again @Adam for the reply, i used your first and second suggestion but nothing has changed yet.